# What would be a fast way to adding new lines of code at the beginning and end of all my files?

Tags: php, regex, dreamweaver

This might be a silly question but is there a way to wrap lines of code around all my PHP scripts without having to go through each one and manually doing it? I have 200 scripts and would like a fast solution.

I am using Dreamweaver, so I was thinking maybe I could use a regular expression to do this quickly, but sadly I am not too good with regular expressions.

I would like to wrap my scripts with

```
<?php
require_once dirname(FILE) . '/../header.php';
?>
```

and

```
<?php
require_once dirname(FILE) . '/../footer.php';
?>
```

Comment: What would you use a regular expression for? Use [`glob()`](http://php.net/glob) recursively et voila. Get content, add pre and post stuff, write to file. I'm quite sure you could do this in a bash script as well and speed up a bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

php script with below code can write the desired code to start and end of each files in a folder.

```
$code_at_start = "<?php
require_once dirname(FILE) . '/../header.php';
?>";

$code_at_end ="<?php
require_once dirname(FILE) . '/../footer.php';
?>";

foreach (glob("path/to/files/*") as $filename)
{
    $file = file_get_contents($filename);
    file_put_contents($filename, $code_at_start . $file . $code_at_end ));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Little google would have saved you.
You can use auto append and auto prepend to do what you need.
in your .htaccess file:

## Prepend the file

php_value auto_prepend_file "/dir/path/header.php"

## Append file to bottom of page

php_value auto_append_file "/dir/path/templates/footer.php"

A nice article will explain you this.
http://davidwalsh.name/prepend-append-files-htaccess

Comment: Thanks. Not exactly what I was looking for, but it's good to know these things.